# How to make `Manipulate[]` to show me the result of expression evaluation live (question updated!)?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, visualization, algebra, interactive

I have code that works the way I need:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[-3*x + 2, {x, from, to}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}], {{from, -10, "frm"}, -10, 10, 
  1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{to, 10, "t"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Now I need to make `Manipulate` to also show me the result of corresponding `y` values for each `x` values generated by current position of the sliders (so in total I need two `y` value fields).

Comment: Since you're plotting it, the expression `-3*x + 2` is evaluated at many x positions and results in many y values. The way you're doing it with `y = -3*x + 2` will show the most recently evaluated result. How do you want the program to decide which y value to display? Just the last one evaluated during the plotting?

Comment: @MassDefect Sorry. Thank you for your comment. Just realized that I need the value of two `y` (corresponding to each `x` from sliders). I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly how you want it to look, there are many ways of doing this. One way would be to add text directly to the graph like this:

```
f[x_] := -3 x + 2
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    f[x],
    {x, from, to},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},
    Epilog -> {
      Text["Left: " <> ToString[f[from]], Scaled[{0.95, 0.95}], {1, 1}],
      Text["Right: " <> ToString[f[to]], Scaled[{0.95, 0.90}], {1, 1}]
    }
  ], 
  {{from, -10, "frm"}, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{to, 10, "t"}, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image: Graph with text appended.]

Separating out the function as `f[x_] := -3 x + 2` gives you the option of easily changing the function being plotted and also allows you to more easily call the function with `f[from]` and `f[to]`.

You can use `Style` to adjust how the text appears. You could also use `Row`, `Column`, or `Grid` to place the graph and the two y-values next to each other if you don't want the y-values to appear on the graph itself.

Comment: What is the easiest way and universal way (so I can use any input function) to place text on the top of the graph (so that text is not on the graph)

Answer (score 2):

The `Manipulate` controls do not affect the expression `-3*x + 2` since the control variables do not appear in this expression. The plot iterator causes that expression to be evaluated from `x == from` to `x == to`. The end points of the line specified by `-3*x + 2` are `{from, -3*from+2}` and `{to, -3*to+2}}`. These end points may or may not be in the specified `PlotRange`.

```
Manipulate[
 pts = {{from, -3 from + 2}, {to, -3 to + 2}};
 Column[
  {Row[{"from ", pts[[1]], " to ", pts[[2]]}],
   Plot[-3*x + 2, {x, from, to},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
      Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ pts}]}],
 {{from, -10, "frm"}, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{to, 10, "t"}, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] := -3*x + 2;

Manipulate[Plot[ConditionalExpression[f[x], r[[1]] <= x <= r[[2]]], {x, -20, 20},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point /@ {{r[[1]], Min[20, f[r[[1]]]]}, {r[[2]], Max[-20, f[r[[2]]]]} }, 
    Text[f@r[[1]], Offset[{0, 10}, {r[[1]], Min[20, f[r[[1]]]]}], {0, 0}],
    Text[f@r[[2]], Offset[{0, -10}, {r[[2]], Max[-20, f[r[[2]]]]}], {0, 0}]}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20,
   ClippingStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Red]], 
 Panel[Row[{Dynamic@Pane[{r[[1]], f@r[[1]]}, Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {90, 20}], 
    IntervalSlider[Dynamic[r], {-20, 20}, Method -> "Stop", 
       Appearance -> "Paired", ImageSize -> 300], 
    Dynamic@Pane[{r[[2]], f@r[[2]]}, Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> {90, 20}]}, 
    Spacer[10]],
   Style["x range", 16], Top],
  {{r, {-15, 15}, ""}, None},
  Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]